# I want to be able to move selected verts on the z axis in 3DS Max

Tags: maxscript

I'm trying to streamline creating terrains in 3DS Max, manually, using contour lines, and I want to be able to make a button/script/macro that I can push to move every selected vertex up 1 unit on the z axis.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an existing solution, [Nudge with Arrow Keys](http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/nudge-with-arrow-keys). You can set the nudge amount by editing the macro(s).